# Chisel: how to avoid errors NO DEFAULT SPECIFIED FOR WIRE

Tags: scala, hardware, hdl, digital-logic, chisel

I'm trying to implement a structured read port to Mem:

```
class TagType() extends Bundle()
{
    import Consts._

    val valid = Bool()
    val dirty = Bool()
    val tag   = UInt(width = ADDR_MSB - ADDR_LSB + 1)
}

object TagType
{
    def apply() = new TagType()
}

val tag_read   = TagType()
//val tag_read   = Reg(TagType())
val tag_read_port   = UInt(width = TagType().getWidth)
val tag_ram    = Mem(UInt(width = TagType().getWidth), num_lines , seqRead = false )

when (tag_read) {
    tag_read_port   := tag_ram(line_no)
    tag_read.toBits := tag_read_port

}
```

When I use combinational

```
val tag_read   = TagType()
```

instead of sequential

```
val tag_read   = Reg(TagType())
```

I get errors

```
Cache.scala:39: error: NO DEFAULT SPECIFIED FOR WIRE: /*? in class cache.Cache*/ Chisel.Bool(width=1, connect to 0 inputs: ()) in component class cache.Cache in class cache.TagType
Cache.scala:40: error: NO DEFAULT SPECIFIED FOR WIRE: /*? in class cache.Cache*/ Chisel.Bool(width=1, connect to 0 inputs: ()) in component class cache.Cache in class cache.TagType
Cache.scala:41: error: NO DEFAULT SPECIFIED FOR WIRE: /*? in class cache.Cache*/ Chisel.UInt(width=28, connect to 0 inputs: ()) in component class cache.Cache in class cache.TagType
```

What is the meaning of this error message?

The second question:

Is it possible to have a structured red port a la SystemVerilog, i.e. read directly

```
tag_read.toBites   := tag_ram(line_no)
```

instead of

```
    tag_read_port   := tag_ram(line_no)
    tag_read.toBits := tag_read_port
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do lines do 39/40/41 correspond to?

What does "when (tag_read)" mean? Shouldn't you be using a Bool() inside the when statement and not a object?

What is "line_no"? (sequential reads are performed by registering the address).

What are you trying to accomplish with tag_read = Reg(TagType())... **[edited]** you're creating a register *of type TagType*, not a node with values associated with it.  **Thus I suspect the error is that there is no default/initial value for that register if "tag_read_cond" is not true**.  Using Reg(init=something) will probably fix the error **[end edits]**.

I'd probably lose the object TagType code. I'm not sure what you're trying to do with it.  This code will declare a tagType and give it a set of default values:

```
val tag_read   = new TagType()
tag_read.valid := Bool(false)
tag_read.dirty := Bool(false)
tag_read.tag := UInt(0)

val tag_ram    = Mem(new TagType(), num_lines , seqRead = false )

when (tag_read_cond) {
    tag_read := tag_ram(line_no)
}
```

Chisel gets angry if your variables do not have default values (i.e., there is a path through your logic in which a variable will not get set, since Chisel does not support X's/don't cares).

Although you can ditch most of that code and probably just write this if you don't mind the extra port:

```
val tag_ram    = Mem(new TagType(), num_lines , seqRead = false )
val tag_read = tag_ram(line_no)
```

And for sequential memories:

```
val tag_ram    = Mem(new TagType(), num_lines , seqRead = true )
val tag_read = tag_ram(RegEnable(line_no, tag_read_cond))
```

Note the *address* is registered, with an enable condition that can tell the memory only to read it when evaluated to true.  The Chisel manual gives more examples/explanations on constructing sequential memories.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Sure, it was a type in when(...) condition, actually it was Bool variable for when(...). For initializing default values I found convenient to use companion object's apply method.

Comment: Just a small addition lines do 39/40/41 correspond to valid, dirty, tag fields in the class TagType, thanks!

Comment: Using the object's apply method for initializing default values may be a good idea, but you have to be careful: in this particular case, Reg(TagType()) is creating a register of type TagType, whereas Reg(init=TagType()) will create a register of type TagType with the appropriate initial values after reset.  I admit I don't use this object apply technique, so the above syntax may be incorrect, but hopefully the idea is clear enough.